# Integrate Tamagui with existing Expo React Native app

Tags: react-native, user-interface, expo

After a while of reading Tamagui docs https://tamagui.dev/docs/guides/expo
I think Tamagui is used in Expo only when it is generated along with Expo project with this command  `npm create tamagui`.
If Tamagui actually can be integrated with existing Expo React Native app, please drop me docs or tutorials.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Basically, you'll need to follow some steps...

To work theme, you need to update the **app.json** changing the value of "userInterfaceStyle" to "automatic".

```json
"userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
```

Some dependencies are mandatory to the tamagui's project, so, let's install all of them:

```bash
npx expo install expo-font expo-linear-gradient react-native-reanimated
```

Now, we'll install a bunch of packages:

- tamagui (mandatory)
- @tamagui/shorthands (optional)
- @tamagui/themes (optional)
- @tamagui/font-inter (mandatory, you need at least one font as default)
- @tamagui/animations-react-native (mandatory)
- @tamagui/config (optional)
- @tamagui/babel-plugin (mandatory)
- babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables (mandatory)
- react-native-web (web support)
- react-dom (web support)

The're some optional packages, but I highly recommend you to install too..

```bash
yarn add tamagui @tamagui/shorthands @tamagui/themes @tamagui/font-inter @tamagui/animations-react-native @tamagui/config @tamagui/babel-plugin babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables react-native-web react-dom
```

After that, we need to update our **babel.config.js** like this

```js
process.env.TAMAGUI_TARGET = 'native'; // Don't forget to specify your TAMAGUI_TARGET here

module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ['@tamagui/babel-plugin', {
        components: ['tamagui'],
        config: './tamagui.config.ts',
        logTimings: true
      }],
      ['transform-inline-environment-variables', {
        include: 'TAMAGUI_TARGET',
      }],
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
     ]
  };
};
```

Now we need to create our config file into the project's root directory

```bash
touch tamagui.config.ts
```

And paste the following code into the **tamagui.config.ts**

```
import { createInterFont } from '@tamagui/font-inter';
import { createMedia } from '@tamagui/react-native-media-driver';
import { shorthands } from '@tamagui/shorthands';
import { themes, tokens } from '@tamagui/theme-base';
import { createTamagui } from 'tamagui';
import { createAnimations } from '@tamagui/animations-react-native';

const animations = createAnimations({
  bouncy: {
    type: 'spring',
    damping: 10,
    mass: 0.9,
    stiffness: 100,
  },
  lazy: {
    type: 'spring',
    damping: 20,
    stiffness: 60,
  },
  quick: {
    type: 'spring',
    damping: 20,
    mass: 1.2,
    stiffness: 250,
  }
});
const headingFont = createInterFont();
const bodyFont = createInterFont();
const config = createTamagui({
  animations,
  defaultTheme: 'dark',
  shouldAddPrefersColorThemes: false,
  themeClassNameOnRoot: false,
  shorthands,
  fonts: {
    heading: headingFont,
    body: bodyFont,
  },
  themes,
  tokens,
  media: createMedia({
    xs: { maxWidth: 660 },
    sm: { maxWidth: 800 },
    md: { maxWidth: 1020 },
    lg: { maxWidth: 1280 },
    xl: { maxWidth: 1420 },
    xxl: { maxWidth: 1600 },
    gtXs: { minWidth: 660 + 1 },
    gtSm: { minWidth: 800 + 1 },
    gtMd: { minWidth: 1020 + 1 },
    gtLg: { minWidth: 1280 + 1 },
    short: { maxHeight: 820 },
    tall: { minHeight: 820 },
    hoverNone: { hover: 'none' },
    pointerCoarse: { pointer: 'coarse' },
  })
});

export type AppConfig = typeof config;

declare module 'tamagui' {
  // overrides TamaguiCustomConfig so your custom types
  // work everywhere you import `tamagui`
  interface TamaguiCustomConfig extends AppConfig {}
}

export default config;
```

Add Tamagui provider and theme support into App.tsx

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import { Paragraph, Spacer, TamaguiProvider, Theme, YStack } from "tamagui";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import config from "./tamagui.config";
export default function App() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    Inter: require("@tamagui/font-inter/otf/Inter-Medium.otf"),
    InterBold: require("@tamagui/font-inter/otf/Inter-Bold.otf"),
  });
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <TamaguiProvider config={config}>
      <Theme name={colorScheme === "dark" ? "dark" : "light"}>
        <YStack
          f={1}
          jc='center'
          ai="center"
          backgroundColor={"$backgroundSoft"}>
          <Paragraph color='$color' jc="center">
            {colorScheme}
          </Paragraph>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </YStack>
      </Theme>
    </TamaguiProvider>
  );
}
```

So, after all, we can just run expo with cache clear flag and have fun.

```bash
npx expo start --clear
```

I hope to help you.